# How do you center images that are scaled?

Tags: html, css, image, web

I'm trying to build this [phstream.herokuapp.com](http://phstream.herokuapp.com/)
But the images that users submit can be of any size. So in the img tag I specify one of the dimensions so that the image gets scaled down. But I uploaded a really big picture and this messed up the alignment. So far it's all html.

Comment: You realize that it would help us if you showed us your html right? And if you would then give us your upload code then we can figure out what is going wrong :)

Comment: He mentions his site is at http://phstream.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your style.css file:

```
img {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Tested on your site and working.**

It would be good practice to give your table an ID, e.g. `id="photostream"`, then you can use the CSS selector `#photostream img` to avoid messing up other images which you may want on the page in future.

It would be even better practice to not use tables for your layout, but you can save that for another day.

Answer (score 0):

try this css...

```
.your_table img{
max-width:150px;
height: auto;} /* this img class should be directed to you images */
```